# Edit font in beamer

Tags: beamer, math-mode, fonts, text

I have a presentation on Beamer. I am not satisfied with my font. I need to change two aspects:

1. the text in math mode equal to the font in the normal text.
2. turn off the bold mode.
   Below the output of my code.
   [image]

Comment: What is your complete code in LaTeX that have you created? Please, can you put into your question? Thank you.

Comment: It’s hard to tell exactly what you want without more information, but in general you can give Beamer the `[professionalfonts]` option and load whatever font package you want. See, for example, `fontsetup`. If the package doesn’t load a matching math font automatically, an easy way to make numerals and Latin letters match is to load `\usepackage{mathastext}`.

Comment: For example, in LuaLaTeX or XeTeX, you might try `\usepackage[fira]{fontsetup}` or `\usepackage{unicode-math}\setmainfont{KpSans}\setsansfont{KpSans}\setmonofont{KpMono}\setmathfont{KpMath-Sans}`.

Comment: In PDFTeX, you might try `\usepackage{arev}`, `\usepackage[math]{iwona}` or `\usepackage[sfmath]{kpfonts}`.